# Cannot boot to Windows 10 from 'Express Gate Cloud' on Asus Eee PC 1225b Notebook

Tags: windows-10, express-gate

The power button isn't working on my Asus Eee PC 1225b Notebook.

The only way I can boot up is by booting into `Asus Express Gate Cloud` (which is a different button that starts this Asus mini-os with 4 apps) then pressing `Switch OS` to boot into Windows 7.

I decided to upgrade to Windows 10. After upgrade it worked fine (although without performance improvement IMO), and restarted.

But after shutdown and starting the Asus Express Gate Cloud, the "switch OS" button does not work - leads to a black screen and remains stuck there until I take out the battery.

Any ideas?